# openvpn - File exists when adding peer

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to connect to a vpn with `openvpn` but I get the following error

```
Tue Jul 11 10:38:38 2017 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 192.168.99.14 peer 192.168.99.13
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Tue Jul 11 10:38:38 2017 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
```

I read the other posts about people having this problem and they solved by checking the `route` table and seeing that they had repeated routes, but after checking mine and deleting all that is involved with `192.168.99.13` on `tun0` I still couldn't add the route. This is my routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.52.44.1      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s31f6
0.0.0.0         192.168.252.1   0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp1s0
10.38.192.13    10.52.44.1      255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 enp0s31f6
10.38.192.13    192.168.252.1   255.255.255.255 UGH   600    0        0 wlp1s0
10.52.44.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s31f6
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 br-846a2b655049
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-846a2b655049
192.168.99.1    192.168.99.13   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
192.168.99.13   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.252.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     600    0        0 wlp1s0
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add it "by hand"?

Comment: @Lenniey no, I get the same error.

Comment: Why are there routes for interface `tun0`?

Comment: @Lenniey they are added when I try to connect with the `openvpn` command.

Comment: ...of course, sorry, I can't read. Could you add your OpenVPN server config? It seems you try to add a redundant route.

Comment: @Lenniey not sure if this is what you asked for, but I just edited the post. Thanks.

Comment: No. This is `/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf`. We need `/etc/openvpn/server.conf` (or similar).

Comment: @Lenniey It seems that I don't have a server.conf. Checked on that path and in opt.

Comment: _Or similar_. It doesn't have to be named `server.conf`. What distro are you using...? Are you even in control of the VPN server? Or do you just try to connect to _some_ VPN?

Comment: @Lenniey I search by the key 'openvpn' in the file system, but nothing apart that file. No, I don't have control of the vpn, it's from other location of the company where I work.